# Clang 3.7.0 complains of class not being literal because it is not an aggregate and has no constexpr constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr, clang++

The following code compiles fine in GCC (4.9.3) and VC++ (19.00.23506) but gives these error in Clang (3.7.0).

> error: constexpr function's return type 'Foo' is not a literal type
>
> note: 'Foo' is not literal because it is not an aggregate and has no
>   constexpr constructors other than copy or move constructors

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    std::vector<int> m_vec;
    Foo(const int *foo, std::size_t size=0):m_vec(foo, foo+size)
    {;}
    //Foo(const std::initializer_list<int> &init):m_vec{init}
    //{;}
};


template <std::size_t N>
constexpr Foo make_fooArray(const int (&a)[N]) noexcept
{
    return {a,N};
}


int main()
{
    Foo f{ make_fooArray({1,2,3}) };

    for (auto i : f.m_vec)
        std::cout<< i <<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Code running on rextester:

[GCC & VC](http://rextester.com/KTYW81035)

[Clang](http://rextester.com/WWB86885)

Can you please clarify whether this is a compiler bug or have I missed something? What does the C++11 standard say?

---

Here is one other case where it compiles in GCC and VC but not in Clang.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t sizeOf_fooArray(const T (&)[N]) noexcept
{
    return N;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<< sizeOf_fooArray({16,20,53,87,54,7}) <<std::endl;
}
```

However, if you alias the int[] and explicitly use it to specify the type of the initializer_list, then it works in all compilers.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t sizeOf_fooArray(const T (&)[N]) noexcept
{
    return N;
}

using intArray = int[]; //Added

int main()
{
    std::cout<< sizeOf_fooArray(intArray{16,20,53,87,54,7}) <<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the compilers are right.

With function templates, in general, it's possible that one instantiation meets the requirements for a `constexpr` function, but another doesn't. Normally, that means `constexpr` effectively gets ignored silently for those instantiations that don't meet the requirements. Example:

```
template <typename T> constexpr T f(T v) { return v; }
```

Both the `f<int>` and `f<std::string>` instantiations are valid, but `f<std::string>` cannot be called in a constant expression.

However, as an exception to that rule, if there isn't *any* possible template argument that could lead to an instantiation that meets the usual requirements for `constexpr` functions, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. This means compilers are at liberty to ignore this rule entirely, but they are equally allowed to diagnose the code as a fatal error.

In general, it's not possible to reliably detect violations of this rule, that's why no diagnostic is required. Some compilers try harder than others to still give some diagnostics.

All of this is described in the standard in [dcl.constexpr]p6:

> If the instantiated template specialization of a `constexpr` function template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor, that specialization is still a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor, even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a constant expression. If no specialization of the template would satisfy the requirements for a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor when considered as a non-template function or constructor, the template is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Comment: That's brilliant! It felt like there was a deeper answer than just a compiler bug. I've actually tried your explanation and saw the results. Same code in GCC=http://rextester.com/OMFA48021 , Clang=http://rextester.com/OYUZW55722